# Getting SQL Server error: conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, datetime, null

I am working with data stored in SQL Server and I am having troubles inserting NULLS into a `DATETIME` column. Ideas?

I'm using a SQL Server database.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE loadedmoves_table
(
     ... 
     date_field DATETIME, 
     PRIMARY KEY (blabla)
);
```

`Insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table (..., date_field) 
    SELECT ..., date_field 
    FROM sample_view 
    ORDER BY PK;
```

Comment: it's helpful to know which db engine you're using, and a sample of an insert query as well

Comment: ... and of course the DDL is helpful. Maybe the column is set to not nullable. *I am having troubles inserting NULLS* and what is the trouble you have?

Comment: Is the problem that you want to insert nulls but can't, or that you don't want to insert nulls but find that you are doing? Either way some same code, sample data and your table definition(s) will help

Comment: What error you got

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using

TRY_CAST(date_field AS DATETIME),

in the SELECT statement

Answer (score -3):

Remove **not-null constraint** from a column and then Run The insert Query
Like.

```
insert into table_name (column) values(values);
```

in this query don't use the **date-time** column name in **columns**

Comment: The DB is MSSQL

Schema creation

CREATE TABLE loadedmoves_table(
...
date_field DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (blabla));

Insert Statement


INSERT 
INTO 
sample_table(
...
date_field
)

SELECT 
...
date_field
FROM sample_view
ORDER BY PK;

Comment: Changing the nullability of a column will NOT affect the ability to convert a string to the appropriate datatype. And suggesting the use of a string datatype to store temporal data is a very poor suggestion and will allow nonsense values to be inserted. Basically this approach is just pushing the problem farther into a system which will make it more fragile, less accurate, and more expensive (in terms of development and maintenance costs).